# Generate a vector only when callback function called

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I want to create a date time vector with a MATLAB user interface , so far i ave created all the edit boxes and buttons and they work fine , but there are 2 small problems i am facing

1) The pushbutton_cb3 function only retrieves datestring from the edit bones only if i press enter on the dates , how can i remove this?
2) I want the funtion pushbutton_cb3 to return the value somewhere I have mentioned in the code , a function `waitfor` look pretty good but I dont know how to use it here
Help will be highly appreciated

```
function AddClassCalender
f = figure('Name', 'AddClassCalender');
EditBoxHandle1 = uicontrol(f, 'Style', 'Edit','Tag','edit1',... 
    'Units','normalized','Position', [0.05 0.9 0.2 0.05], 'Callback',@edit_callback);
EditBoxHandle2 = uicontrol(f, 'Style', 'Edit','Tag','edit2', ...
    'Units','normalized','Position', [0.3 0.9 0.2 0.05], 'Callback',@edit_callback2);
ButtonHandle1 = uicontrol(f, 'Style', 'PushButton', ...
    'String', 'Select the starting date', ...
    'Units','normalized','Position', [0.05 0.85 0.22 0.05], ...
    'callback', @pushbutton_cb1);
ButtonHandle2 = uicontrol(f, 'Style', 'PushButton', ...
    'String', 'Select the starting date', ...
    'Units','normalized','Position', [0.3 0.85 0.22 0.05], ...
    'callback', @pushbutton_cb2);
TextHandle = uicontrol(f, 'Style', 'Text', ...
    'String', 'Interval(mins):', ...
    'Horizontalalignment', 'left', ...
    'Units','normalized','Position', [0.6 0.9 0.2 0.05]);
EditBoxHandle3 = uicontrol(f, 'Style', 'Edit','Tag','edit3', ...
    'Units','normalized','Position', [0.7 0.9 0.2 0.05], 'Callback',@edit_callback3);
ButtonHandle3 = uicontrol(f, 'Style', 'PushButton', ...
    'String', 'Generate', ...
    'Units','normalized','Position', [0.7 0.85 0.2 0.05], ...
    'callback', @pushbutton_cb3);
%% I WANT THE PUSHBUTTON TO RETURN THE DATETIME VECTOR HERE SO I CAN USE IT FURTHER MORE 
uiwait(f)
    function pushbutton_cb1(hcbo, eventStruct)
        uicalendar('Weekend', [1 0 0 0 0 0 1], ...
            'SelectionType', 1, ...
            'DestinationUI', EditBoxHandle1);
    end
    function pushbutton_cb2(hcbo, eventStruct)
        uicalendar('Weekend', [1 0 0 0 0 0 1], ...
            'SelectionType', 1, ...
            'DestinationUI', EditBoxHandle2);
    end
    function edit_callback(hcbo, eventStruct)
       Date = hcbo.String;
       hcbo.UserData  = Date;
    end
    function edit_callback2(hcbo, eventStruct)
       Date = hcbo.String;
       hcbo.UserData  = Date
    end
    function edit_callback3(hcbo, eventStruct)
       Interval = hcbo.String;
       hcbo.UserData  = Interval
    end


    function pushbutton_cb3(hcbo, eventStruct)
        date1 = findobj('Tag','edit1');
        date2 = findobj('Tag','edit2');
        interval = findobj('Tag','edit3');
        data1 = date1.UserData
        data2 = date2.UserData
        int_str = interval.UserData
        interv = str2num(int_str)
        interval_cal = 1/(1440/interv);
        datevector = datetime(data1,'Format','dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'):interval_cal:datetime(data2)
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the Financial Toolbox, so let's consider in my example that I enter manually the dates in the fields (I check to be sure to enter the same string than uicalendar).

You can use `waitfor` instead of `uiwait`. This way, the application will continue only when the excepted variable has been changed (In my examplen, I put the data in `ButtonHandle3.UserData`

```
function [returnedVector] = AddClassCalender

f = figure('Name', 'AddClassCalender');

EditBoxHandle1 = uicontrol(f, 'Style', 'Edit','Tag','edit1',... 
    'Units','normalized','Position', [0.05 0.9 0.2 0.05], 'Callback',@edit_callback);
EditBoxHandle2 = uicontrol(f, 'Style', 'Edit','Tag','edit2', ...
    'Units','normalized','Position', [0.3 0.9 0.2 0.05], 'Callback',@edit_callback2);
ButtonHandle1 = uicontrol(f, 'Style', 'PushButton', ...
    'String', 'Select the starting date', ...
    'Units','normalized','Position', [0.05 0.85 0.22 0.05], ...
    'callback', @pushbutton_cb1);
ButtonHandle2 = uicontrol(f, 'Style', 'PushButton', ...
    'String', 'Select the starting date', ...
    'Units','normalized','Position', [0.3 0.85 0.22 0.05], ...
    'callback', @pushbutton_cb2);
TextHandle = uicontrol(f, 'Style', 'Text', ...
    'String', 'Interval(mins):', ...
    'Horizontalalignment', 'left', ...
    'Units','normalized','Position', [0.6 0.9 0.2 0.05]);
EditBoxHandle3 = uicontrol(f, 'Style', 'Edit','Tag','edit3', ...
    'Units','normalized','Position', [0.7 0.9 0.2 0.05], 'Callback',@edit_callback3);
ButtonHandle3 = uicontrol(f, 'Style', 'PushButton', ...
    'String', 'Generate', ...
    'Units','normalized','Position', [0.7 0.85 0.2 0.05], ...
    'callback', @pushbutton_cb3);

%% I WANT THE PUSHBUTTON TO RETURN THE DATETIME VECTOR HERE SO I CAN USE IT FURTHER MORE 
waitfor(ButtonHandle3, 'UserData')

% Do what you want with the data here, I choose to return it and to close the figure;
returnedVector = ButtonHandle3.UserData;
delete(f);


    function pushbutton_cb1(hcbo, eventStruct)
        uicalendar('Weekend', [1 0 0 0 0 0 1], ...
            'SelectionType', 1, ...
            'DestinationUI', EditBoxHandle1);
    end
    function pushbutton_cb2(hcbo, eventStruct)
        uicalendar('Weekend', [1 0 0 0 0 0 1], ...
            'SelectionType', 1, ...
            'DestinationUI', EditBoxHandle2);
    end
    function edit_callback(hcbo, eventStruct)
       Date = hcbo.String;
       hcbo.UserData  = Date;
    end
    function edit_callback2(hcbo, eventStruct)
       Date = hcbo.String;
       hcbo.UserData  = Date
    end
    function edit_callback3(hcbo, eventStruct)
       Interval = hcbo.String;
       hcbo.UserData  = Interval
    end


    function pushbutton_cb3(hcbo, eventStruct)
        date1 = findobj('Tag','edit1');
        date2 = findobj('Tag','edit2');
        interval = findobj('Tag','edit3');
        data1 = date1.UserData;
        data2 = date2.UserData;
        int_str = interval.UserData;
        interv = str2num(int_str);
        interval_cal = 1/(1440/interv);
        datevector = datetime(data1,'Format','dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'):interval_cal:datetime(data2);
        % I set the returned data in UserData in order to finish the waitfor
        hcbo.UserData = datevector;
    end

end
```